# How can I concatenate text from multiple rows in a Schematiq table into a single value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, schematiq

In Microsoft Excel I have a Schematiq table that contains values in a number of rows:

[image]

I would like to concatenate all of the row values into a single value and store this in a cell delimited by the text "-colour-"

So from the example above, the desired output would be: red-colour-yellow-colour-pink-colour-green-colour-orange-colour-purple-colour-blue

Is this possible using a custom aggregate function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using a custom aggregation function. Maybe you already tried something like this:

```
=tbl.Group(F7, , "A")
```

You'll have found that you get `#VALUE!` because Schematiq tries to add up the values in column A, and can't because they are not numbers.

When you supply a custom function to `tbl.Group`, it uses it on the first two values in the column, then that result and the next value, and so on. So to replicate the default behaviour you could use something like:

```
(x, y) => x + y
```

Based on your question though, you want to combine two text values using a function like this:

```
(x, y) => x & '-colour-' & y
```

..which would look like this as a call to `tbl.Group`:

```
=tbl.Group(F7, , "A", "(x, y) => x & '-colour-' & y")
```

You can then wrap this in a call to `tbl.GetValue` to put the answer straight into a cell.

Alternatively, you could do this, which gets all the values from the table column and uses `txt.Join` to combine them:

```
=txt.Join(tbl.GetValues(F7), "-colour-")
```

This is probably simpler in this specific case.

(incidentally, I'm part of the Schematiq team)